# Как сделать кнопку "Открыть" неактивной, пока не выбран radiobutton?

Tags: javascript

```html
<div class="first-block">
  <h1 class="task__title">Tasks</h1>
  <button class="button">Открыть</button>
  <div class="task-list"></div>
</div>
<template class="task-template">
  <label for="task" class="form__label">
    <input type="radio" name="task" class="form__check">
    <span class="form__task-text"></span>
  </label>
</template>
```

Comment: Зачем используете **type='radio'**, если у вас одно значение? Для этого лучше подойдет **type='checkbox'**, т.к. с одним единственным **type='radio'** вы не сможете его "отжать". Покажите ваши попытки реализации задуманного и с чем именно возникли сложности?

Comment: Значений несколько, в JS прописан код, который вставляет пять разных значений (взятых из массива) по заготовленному шаблону.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const inputCases = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="task"]`);
const button = document.querySelector(`button.button`);

button.disabled = !Array.from(inputCases).some((input) => input.checked);
inputCases.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener(`change`, (event) => {
    button.disabled = !Array.from(inputCases).some((input) => input.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="first-block">
  <h1 class="task__title">Tasks</h1>
  <button class="button">Открыть</button>
  <div class="task-list"></div>
</div>
<label class="form__label">
  <input type="radio" name="task" class="form__check">
  <span class="form__task-text">Крассная</span>
</label> или
<label class="form__label">
  <input type="radio" name="task" class="form__check">
  <span class="form__task-text">Синяя</span>
</label>
```

Comment: `const button = document.querySelector('.button');
 const radio = document.querySelector('.form__check');

button.setAttribute('disabled', true);

const openButton = () => {
    if (radio.checked) {
        button.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
    else {
        button.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    }
};`
Сделал таким образом, кнопка неактивна с загрузки страницы, но даже после выбора радиобаттон она не разблокируется, в чем проблема?

Comment: @user538544 подправьте в вопросе. В таком хаотичном виде не понятно, что вы делали и что у вас не получилось.

Comment: в change листенере может и не стоит доп проверку делать, а сразу кнопку разблокировать

Comment: @PavelNazarian я писал код так, чтобы потом при добавлении функций оно продолжило работать. Если автор ещё добавит возможность отключения radio, то мой код продолжит работать правильно. А если просто разблокировать, то тут возникнут проблемы. Для конкретно примера сверху можно реализовать и так как вы предложили.